# How to implement a useWatch in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have implemented two hooks. They are useWatch1 and useWatch2, respectively.

> The function of useWatch is to execute a cb function when the listening value changes.

The user first clicks the `ADD COUNT` button a few times, and then the count value will increase. Then the user clicks the `ADD ID` button, and the `count` value will be set to `0`. `useWatch2` meets expectations, but `useWatch1` cannot. I would like to know why?

```js
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

function useWatch1(current, cb) {
  const isFirstRender = useRef(true);
  const prevRef = useRef(null);

  if (isFirstRender.current) {
    prevRef.current = current;
    isFirstRender.current = false;
  } else if(prevRef.current !== current){
    prevRef.current = current;
    cb();
  }
}

function useWatch2(current, cb) {
  const [prev, setPrev] = useState(current);

  if (current !== prev) {
    setPrev(current);
    cb();
  }
}

function MyCpm({ id }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // useWatch1(id, () => {
  //   setCount(0);
  // });

  useWatch2(id, () => {
    setCount(0);
  });

  console.log("render", count);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount((c) => c + 1);
        }}
      >
        ADD COUNT
      </button>
      <span>count: {count}</span>
      <span>-----</span>
      <span>id: {id}</span>
    </>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [id, setId] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setId((id) => id + 1);
        }}
      >
        ADD ID
      </button>
      <MyCpm id={id}></MyCpm>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useWatch1` would work if you do not use [React Strict Mode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode). With Strict Mode enabled, React will (re)render the component twice to allow the programmer to find accidental impurities in the component. The first rerender will set `prevRef.current` to the new value, so the values will no longer differ on the **second rerender, which is the one that is used to update the DOM**. `useWatch2` has no such issue as React will simply ignore state updates on the first (discarded) rerender.

Comment: Learned something new about StrictMode! I knew it was rendered twice, but I didn't know the second render was always the one that "won"

Answer (score 0):

You've overcomplicated the situation - there's documented ability to "reset" state (unmount/mount) components [using keys](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#option-2-resetting-state-with-a-key)

```
<MyCpm id={id} key={id}></MyCpm>
```

Comment: The key can reset the entire component, but this is not what I hope to happen. Because in practical situations, there are still some states that cannot be reset, but I did not write them out in the examples.

Comment: @user15163984 - you've still overcomplicated it, you could've just lifted the count state up and reset it when the id changed in the parent. Simpler code, less custom code, more declarative. The question is interesting, the implementation is hard on the head.